# In Safari 13, the option to Export to HAR is disabled (greyed out). How can I enable this?

Tags: web, safari, macos-catalina

In using Safari 13.1.2 on OSX 10.15.6, I am using the developer tools to inspect network traffic.  I have Preserve Logs checked but the option to Export HAR is disabled (greyed out).

How can I enable this?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What worked for me was refreshing the page while keeping the Network tab open.

Comment: Thank you, a page refresh after loading Developer Tools and having the Network Tab open was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have that option I had to right click a network request and then export har.

[image]